can'tdelete schema in redshift
I have a schema in Redshift with over 12,000 tables. I want to drop the schema, but the operation isn’t completing due to the large number of tables. I can't even execute a SELECT query, and there’s no permission error; it’s just that the sheer volume of tables is causing issues. How can I resolve this?
Tried to use Drop schema, Write drop statement, nothing worked.

What messages or errors are you getting?

it just keeps executing and doesn't stop

Can you confirm that if you delete a single table that the sql statement completes as expected?

And just to confirm you have the right permissions to delete these objects?

It is best to show the commands you've tried and the errors they produce as this will give you the best advice.  Assuming you have permission to drop the schema you should be using the CASCADE option to DROP SCHEMA to remove the tables and all other objects in the schema.

If Redshift is unresponsive, then reboot it and re-establish a connection again (confirm it with a SELECT statement). Then, continue to experiment.

It’s not hanging, it’s working, trying to drop all of them in a single transaction. You stop the query half way through, it rolls back. There’s no way to see how far it’s gotten. Best bet is to delete the tables in batches. For example in datagrip you can select a few hundred delete statements and “run as single script” so it runs much faster than just selecting all of them and clicking run, having it go line by line. To get all your delete statements do
Select ‘;drop table myschema.’ || tablename 
from pg_tables where schema_name=‘myschema’

